# Primary group in the security descriptor (SD)

Tags: windows, security, active-directory

Every SD in Windows has a `primary group` field. It is there for quite a while and I suspect there are historical reasons for it to be there, like compatibility with LDAP. So my questions are:

1. Does anybody knows how it is used in our days? In Windows 8 for example? Does it affect anything?
2. What are the historical roots? Where was it introduced and why? This may reveal a lot.
3. Any other thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Compatibility with POSIX.  Unless you're using the POSIX subsystem, I don't believe it affects anything.

Comment: Post it as an answer, please so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary group exists for compatibility with POSIX.  Unless you're using the POSIX subsystem, or are using Active Directory as an LDAP service for UNIX systems, I don't believe it affects anything.

(One other edge case: depending on which API you're using, if you want to remove the user from the primary group you might need to use a different function than you would for a normal group membership.)

Comment: Can you confirm that Active Directory has/does not have this field on a user object?

Comment: It does.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679375(v=vs.85).aspx for reference.  Which is a good point; you might use the primary group if you're using AD to authenticate UNIX clients, although I'm not sure whether that's the usual approach.  Answer edited accordingly.